# LaTeX - Get the name of an unnumbered subsection

Tags: latex, tex

I'm writing a LaTeX document and I need a way to get the name of the subsection I'm in. I know how to get the name of a subsection as long as it's numbered, the problem is that my subsection isn't.

**Numbered Subsection**

```
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
```

And then you just have to use the following code to get the name of your subsection:

```
\subsection{numbered}    
\Subsectionname %Will be "numbered"
```

**Unnumbered section**

My problem comes when I try to do the following:

```
\subsection{numbered}  
\subsection*{unnumbered}    
\Subsectionname %Will be "numbered"
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to get the name of the unnumbered subsection.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping into the sectional *marks* only work for sectional units that are numbered as unnumbered sectional units do not update any marks.

Below we tap into [`\@startsection`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) to capture the type of sectional unit *first*, after which we set the title as part of `\@sect` - a numbered sectional unit - or `\@ssect` - an unnumbered/starred sectional unit. The title is captured in a unit-specific macro: `\sectiontitle` for a `\section[*]`, `\subsectiontitle` for a `\subsection[*]`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@startsection}% <cmd>
  {\@namedef{@sectype}{#1}}% <pre>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\@namedef{\@sectype title}{#8}\@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@ssect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\@namedef{\@sectype title}{#5}\@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Section name: \sectiontitle

\subsection{A subsection}
Subsection name: \subsectiontitle

\subsection*{Another subsection}
Subsection name: \subsectiontitle

\end{document}
```

[`titleref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleref) provides a far easier interface:

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75168/5764
\usepackage{titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\TR@currentTitle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Section name: \currentname

\subsection{A subsection}
Subsection name: \currentname

\subsection*{Another subsection}
Subsection name: \currentname

\end{document}
```